# Using awk how to print selective columns when a condition is met

Tags: awk

Problem:
I want to list all pods matching expression "test-" for which my expression works well and then I want to print only $1 and $2 if that expression exists in row. how can I?
I want to do this with single AWK and not pipe again.

```
 kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=spec.nodeName=node1,status.phase!=Succeeded --no-headers | awk '$1 ~ /maglev-/'
```

output

```
test-78ac951e-89a6-4199-87a4-db8a1b8b054f   export-4cb52be4-8a90-400-ilxr4b-avexport-xavierisp-sjc4--b76888-b3f   1/1   Running   0     20h
test-78ac951e-89a6-4199-87a4-db8a1b8b054f   export-9b55f0d5-071d-431-1d2ux0-avexport-xavierisp-sjc4--a4dd85-102   1/1   Running   0     17h
```

```
dtlu @ dtlu16 ~
└─ $ ▶ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=spec.nodeName=node1,status.phase!=Succeeded --no-headers | awk '$1 ~ /test-/' '{print $1,$2}'
```

output actual:

```
awk: cannot open {print $1,$2} (No such file or directory)
```

expected output

```
test-78ac951e-89a6-4199-87a4-db8a1b8b054f   export-4cb52be4-8a90-400-ilxr4b-avexport-xavierisp-sjc4--b76888-b3f

test-78ac951e-89a6-4199-87a4-db8a1b8b054f   export-9b55f0d5-071d-431-1d2ux0-avexport-xavierisp-sjc4--a4dd85-102
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incorrect `awk` syntax by providing `'{$1, $2}'` in separate quotes after the pattern match. They need to be combined together as one. The syntax you have makes `awk` believe that `'{$1, $2}'` as file name to run the expression on.

```
awk '$1 ~ /test-/{print $1, $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that as simple as:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=spec.nodeName=node1,status.phase!=Succeeded --no-headers | egrep "^test-" | awk '{print $1" "$2}'
```

?

Comment: I want to do this with single AWK and not pipe again.

Comment: Use: `awk '$1 ~ /test-/{print $1,$2}'`

Comment: that was it. post your answer and i will check it. thanks a lot

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. Btw `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`.

Comment: @EdMorton by combining grep with awk I never need to google for the syntax or ask a question on stackoverflow ;) you don't always need to optimize everything

Comment: I understand but what grep does (print a line that matches a regexp) is a small but fundamental part of what awk does (print **or otherwise act on** a line that matches a regexp **or other condition**) so if you know awk then you don't need to google the syntax for "matches a regexp" that you'd otherwise use grep for and if you don't know awk then you're missing out an extremely useful, efficient, simple, portable, robust way to manipulate text. For example, `egrep "^test-" | awk '{print $1" "$2}'` can be written as just  `awk '/^test-/{print $1" "$2}'` - not very complicated to figure out!

Comment: But no so simple to figure out as well! As many others do, I use grep everyday and awk only from time to time to print column(s).

Comment: I understand that too, I used grep+sed+shell for 10+ years before being convinced to try awk - 25 years later I regret not learning to use awk much sooner. But - whatever works for you...